# How to find intersection point between lines matlab

Tags: image, matlab, lines

I have 2 or 3 hough lines drawn on the edges of the road these lines intersect at the horizon point where the road and the sky meet. I want to find and plot this point. How can i achieve this using hough lines?
An idea rings in my mind of voting map how can i create voting map ?
This is my code. Assume hough lines from the edges of the road, intersect and make a triangle with the road area inside.
here is my output image

[image]

```
 I  =  imread('1.jpg');


 J = imfilter(I, fspecial('gaussian', [17 17], 5), 'symmetric');

se3 = strel('disk', 4);

%J = imdilate(J, se);

J = rgb2gray(J);

BW = edge(J, 'sobel');
BW = imdilate(BW, se3);

[H T R] = hough(BW);

P  = houghpeaks(H, 4);

lines = houghlines(J, T, R,P);
 Q = figure(5);
 imshow(I) 
 hold on;

 xy1 = [lines(3).point1; lines(3).point2];
 line1 =  plot(xy1(:,1),xy1(:,2),'LineWidth',6,'Color','blue');

  xy2 = [lines(4).point1; lines(4).point2];
 line2 =  plot(xy2(:,1),xy2(:,2),'LineWidth',6,'Color','blue');

  xy3 = [lines(2).point1; lines(2).point2];
 line3 =  plot(xy3(:,1),xy3(:,2),'LineWidth',6,'Color','blue');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have equations of the lines then you just need to solve 3 equations with two unknowns (x,y of intersection point). Use matlab matrix division operator (\) for that.
For example:
You have 3 lines:

- X + 2Y = 7,
- 3X + 4Y = 8,
- 5X + 6Y = 9

The code is:

```
A = [1,2;3,4;5,6]
b = [7,8,9]'
x = A\b
```

If you dont know the equations but only pixels in which those lines pass then drow all the lines on a black image and search for maximal pixel value. The intersection point will be 3 times brighter than the rest of lines.
If you want to reduce run time than start from pixel on arbitrary line and iterate over its neighbours until you find the intersection point.

Comment: Thanks DanielHsH . If you can only give me a code sample to start on ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not having the equations or points of the line makes it harder. If this is just a one time operation, and you only have 3 lines, I'd suggest using [`ginput`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/ginput.html) and selecting the points by hand.

So after you've drawn your figure, type `[x,y]=ginput;` at the command line. This should bring focus to your figure and you'll see a cross-hair that you can move over the figure. Now click on the three points that you are interested in and then press enter. Now `x` and `y` will contain the coordinates of the three points.

Comment: I appreciate you help but its not what im looking for. This code will be implemented in the video and real time. im using hough lines lets suppose the hough lines are not yet the part of the image but these lines intersect. i want that point as vanishing point or horizon of the road. do i make sense? sorry for my english :(

Comment: @Hasham: That's the kind of info that you should provide in your question so that others understand what you're trying to do... please edit your question to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

The overall strategy is the following:
1. Pick two points on each hough line
2. Use these two points to get the line equation
3. Use the line equations to find their intersection point

You have to figure out how to pick two points on each line, say for line 1 it's p1 and p2 and line 2 it's q1 and q2. Then if p[1|2], q[1|2] are 2D row vectors then

```
line1 = GetLineFromTwoImagePoints(p1, p2);
line2 = GetLineFromTwoImagePoints(q1, q2);
intersection = GetPointFromTwoImageLines(line1, line2);

function line = GetLineFromTwoImagePoints( one, two )
    line = cross([one 1], [two 1]);
end

function point = GetPointFromTwoImageLines( one, two )
    p = cross(one, two);
    point = [p(1)/p(3) p(2)/p(3)];
end
```